# What RegEx in JavaScript would replace a token surrounded by either \W and/or anchors (^ and/or $)?

Tags: javascript, regex

What RegEx would replace a single `'m'` letter with (e.g.) a number, assuming that `'m'` must be single letter (`'m'` in `'m.n'` or `'L m'` should be replaced, but `'m'` in `'mind'` or `'1m'` must not) and may appear in beginning of string or at the end ?

#### Examples:

`'mind'.replace(exp,'7')`      => `'mind'`
`'m-ind'.replace(exp,'7')`               => `'7-ind'`
`'-m-ind'.replace(exp,'7')`                   => `'-7-ind'`

(`exp` must be identical in all above examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but this will only match letter `m` which is not part of a word:

`\b(m)\b`

**EDIT:**

At the suggestion of [Qtax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107152/qtax), you can remove the capturing group if you only want to replace `m` and nothing more:

`\bm\b`

Comment: Why the capturing group? It's useless here and can be removed.

Comment: It's not needed for the simple replace here, but I thought he might want to do a more complicated replace, plus it's easier to understand the RegExp with it there.

Comment: D'oh! I missed that shorthand\anchor! without the capturing group - that's exactly what I meant... :-S